# Is there a way to execute a Rust function in an independent process?

Tags: process, rust

I have a program that takes an argument called `start-master`. When it is passed, I need to start a daemon listening on a port.

I have a function:

```
fn startMaster() {
    // Sockets, connections, logic, etc
}
```

Can I make a new process that executes `startMaster` in the background so that a user can call `./mainprogram start-master` without using bash's `&`?

The process has to be independent from the main process as it must not stop when the caller process finishes. I need a non blocking solution.

My main program would be:

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let arg1 = &args[1];
    // ...
    match arg1.as_ref() {
        "start-master" => {
            // Starts process in background which executes startMaster function
        }
        _ => println!("Not valid argument")
    }

    // Ends program but now there is an active daemon 
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html

Comment: and https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_exe.html

Comment: I've read the Command docs. But as I understood It starts a **child** process. So if the parent process finish, the child process will too

Comment: I'm also testing right now and Command is also blocking

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple additional constraints on a given answer, but those constraints are not clearly expressed in the question. If someone had provided an answer with the content of the above suggestions, it seems likely they would have wasted their time. Please help avoid wasting their time (and yours!) by [edit]ing and placing **all** requirements you have in the question (and do so starting with the initial question in the future, please).

Comment: I don't know what are the new requeriments you're talking about. I've edited the question to talk about independence, but I think It was explicit in the title. That's why a Child process does not work for me. Also, as the last comment in the program indicates, I need a non blocking solution. Thank you!

Comment: *`Command` is not a solution for me as it waits for the process to finish* — the documentation directly contradicts your point: [The standard library does not automatically wait on child processes (not even if the `Child` is dropped), it is up to the application developer to do so](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html). Are you saying that the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: My bad! I don't know why a child process still works even Its parent has finished... But It worked! If you want to submit an answer I'll accept It as the correct one. If you don't want to, I'll submit my own later. Thank so much